# Handling a controlled input when using RTK Query in React

Tags: react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

When using RTK Query, you abstract away all the state management that comes with data fetching -- you call an endpoint and the documents are loaded into a variable, ready for use. Like so:

> const {data: rangesInfo = []} = useGetRangesQuery(userId);

Let's say this `rangesInfo` variable contains a uniquely identifying ID, `uuid`, as well as a number, `rangeValue`, which specifies its position. This number can run from 0 to 100. For the sake of this example, let's imagine these ranges describe a user's food preferences. John is a 0 for sushi and a 100 for pizza. And as the end user clicks around the website, they can load other users' preferences, and so this set of ranges is constantly updating.

This all works fine -- you can call `rangesInfo.map(range => <RangeComponent key={range.uuid} rangeValue={range.rangeValue}/>)`, and this will render a collection of children components, which all know how to display the UI of the actual HTML `input[type=range]`.

But when using an range slider input in React, you must choose between either a controlled or an uncontrolled input. React's preference is for the input to be controlled by the state of its parent. In this case, the state of its parent is an RTK black box, and if you want to modify the cached data you must invalidate it, typically by triggering a `mutation`. This is RTK Query's term for a POST or an UPDATE request that will affect data in your backend. The thing is that in Chrome, a range input's `onChange` event triggers dozens of times a second, and it seems ridiculous to pummel your API with 40 requests when only the last one makes a difference.

That means we have to go with an uncontrolled component. The problem then becomes updating the display of the range when the props change. Because the props *do* change -- RTK is working fine -- but the props no longer have any bearing on the position of the range's value. (Remember, if you want to **control** an input's value via prop, you're no longer described an uncontrolled component!). If we could guarantee that the child components were remounted every time their props changed, we should be in the clear, but that wasn't my experience.

Even though those RangeComponents were given unique ids, and even though [the docs suggest that this is sufficient](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recommendation-fully-uncontrolled-component-with-a-key), the new data was out of sync. When I loaded the page, I had User 0's info, and then I clicked on User 1 I still saw User 0. When I clicked on User 2, now User 1 popped in, and so forth.

My ultimately hacky solution was to attach a `ref` to the input range's DOM, and then use a side effect to dictate the its value, like so:

> useEffect(() => {inputRef.current.value = props.rangeValue})

This solved my consistency problem, but introduced a ton of jank to the UX -- when I set the input range to a new state, it flickers back to its original position briefly.

Is there a way to solve this issue while staying in the RTK Query paradigm?

Answer (score 2):

The no-jank, no-ref-necessary solution: Be extra sure that your child component's key is unique, because RTK is going to rerender it multiple times, and the render that "sticks" may not have the updated props at that point.

My fix was to append the value of the range to the key. So now the code looks like:

`rangesInfo.map(range => <RangeComponent key={range.uuid + rangeValue} rangeValue={range.rangeValue}/>)`

By linking the props and the keys together, you're guaranteeing that React will remount the child component.

Hope this saves somebody some time!